# Use Host Machine's VPN in Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

I am using Virtual Box to create a Ubuntu Virtual Machine. 
On my host machine, I often connect to a VPN network. I want to connect to this VPN from my virtual machine.

Please help!. Let me know if any other details are required

Comment: Sounds like you're making a false assumption there, or what do you mean by "connect". Did you even try it, because in many scenarios it will just work? How do you set up the VPN? From a router or from the host?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual box defaults its network setup to NAT mode. This configuration allows you to share whatever connection your host machine has.

If you are running the network as Bridged then you will not be able to share the connection.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nichardware

Check out the description at the link above and verify your config for your VM.